# Custom value for Condition in Automapper

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have a scenario like

If total number of days is less than 30 days, then I have to set Salary to null

```
this.CreateMap<Foo, Doo>()
    .ForMember(dst => dst.Salary, opt => {
                              opt.Condition(src => src.JoinedDate.Days <= 30));
                              opt.MapFrom(null)
}
```

But I am facing error "cannot find member of type Foo. Parameter name: name". but don't have any property "name".

Question is How to pass null value to destination property in condition check, and retain existing value if days greater than 30.

> opt.MapFrom(null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just combined above two solutions and found answer for my question.

```
ForMember(dst => dst.Salary,
            opt => opt.ResolveUsing((src, dst) => src.JoinedDate.Days <= 30 ? null: dst.Salary));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
this.CreateMap<Foo, Doo>()
    .ForMember(dst => dst.Salary, 
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.JoinedDate.Days <= 30 ? null : src.Salary))
```

**UPD**

To preserve `Salary` from destination use overload of `MapFrom` accepting both source and destination:

```
this.CreateMap<Foo, Doo>()
    .ForMember(dst => dst.Salary, 
        opt => opt.MapFrom((src, dst) => src.JoinedDate.Days <= 30 ? null : dst.Salary))
```

Comment: If condition fails, then I have to retain my existing Salary. so which means `: src.Salary` supposed to be `dst.Salary`, but it is inaccessible

Comment: @Munijagadish what version are you using? Latest one works [fine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eZdsvO) for me.

Comment: Mine is not last version, However both above answers helped to figure out solution.. I will add answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use automapper inline `ResolveUsing`.

```
ForMember(dst => dst.Salary,
            o => o.ResolveUsing(src => src.JoinedDate.Days > 30 ? src.Salary: null));
```

Comment: If condition fails, then I have to retain my existing Salary. so which means `: src.Salary` supposed to be `dst.Salary`, but it is inaccessible